# What happens while skewing a spring?

Tags: springs, coil-spring

I'm trying to design this magazine spring in CAD:
[image]

But this spring should be skewed:

[image]

When designing the spring, there's one problem, one "leg" would need to be longer than the other for the coils to join:
[image]

Even if the metal could expand and contract a bit it would not be able to do as much.

So my question is what should happen when I skew this type of spring?
Some part of it should contract/distort so that both legs have about the same length.

Answer (score 1):

if the connection at the end of the spring is a pin connection and the deformation is small, not a big change in behavior will happen.
we still have
$$F=Kx$$
But if the connection is fixed and is not aligned with the extension of the spring warping and complex torque change the deformation and stresses.

In car springs they take advantage of this slant and the angle of the saddle to get a variable stiffness, K. The suspension will be soft for small bumps and get tougher for big bumps.